# Uncaught TypeError Issue with the Lightning datepicker Introduced in Summer '18

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Following the Summer '18 release, a component that referenced a lightning:input base component of type "date" is now generating an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
>   throws at
>   https://xxx.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-datepicker.js:2:4706

The offending reference looks like this:

```
<lightning:input name="delivery-date" label="Expected Delivery Date" type="date" onblur="{!c.handleBlur}" value="{!v.order.Delivery_Date_Expected__c}" required="true"/>
```

Has anyone experienced this yet? Any guidance on where to even begin troubleshooting or finding a workaround?

Comment: it is causing issues when loading or when you call onBlur event?4

Comment: It errors out after submitting the value in an action.

Comment: Can always file a case with salesforce if the summer update is what broke it. I have an open case with them right now with a bug that I found in the summer release as well.

Comment: Just use mine. If you get an error, at least you or I can fix it: https://github.com/rapsacnz/DatePicker

Comment: facing same issue... any solution  ?

Comment: I just added the code for a stable workaround. At this point I am avoiding the ISO-8601 date format until I understand exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like lightning:input is experiencing issues with handling ISO-8601 formatted date values, so I applied a workaround that I used when I experienced similar issues with the lightning:formattedDateTime component.

Rather than passing the ISO-8601 formatted date to the value attribute of the lightning:input, I run it through the localization service in the JavaScript API to format the date as a simplified 'YYYY-MM-DD' string value.

Using the string value fixed two issues that appeared in Summer '18 - one was this uncaught TypeError, the other being the value being passed to the lightning:input was not displaying until the onBlur event for the input component was fired.

So if you're experiencing similar issues, here is the JavaScript to perform this conversion from ISO-8601 formatted date value to a YYYY-MM-DD string format:

```
let newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 2);

// Hack to get date to display in lightning:input

const newDateString = $A.localizationService.formatDate(newDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
```